# Why UIBarButtonItem not getting clicks in UIToolbar set as inputAccessoryView of UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar, uibaritem, inputaccessoryview

**UIBarItem does not respond to clicks inside UIToolbar which is setup as inputAccessoryView on a UITextField.**

The button does not show click animation when I try to click it, callback does not get called.
My setup looks like:

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *closeDateTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar * datePickerToolbar;
@end
```

I setup toolbar with button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem * doneBtn =
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                target:self
                action:@selector(hidePicker:)];
```

add button to toolbar and set toolbar as `inputAccessoryView` of `UITextField`:

```
    [self.datePickerToolbar setItems:@[doneBtn] animated:NO];
    self.closeDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.datePickerToolbar;
}
```

When I click on `closeDateTextField` the keyboard appears with a `Done` button in toolbar but the button does not respond to click, the `hidePicker:` does not get called.

```
- (void)hidePicker:(id)sender {
    [self.closeDateTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried the following code and it worked just fine. Tested on both iOS 6 & 7 simulator.

```
@interface HSViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *closeDateTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar * datePickerToolbar;

@end

@implementation HSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem * doneBtn =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
     target:self
     action:@selector(hidePicker:)];
    [self.datePickerToolbar setItems:@[doneBtn] animated:NO];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    self.closeDateTextField = textField;
    self.closeDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.datePickerToolbar;
}

- (void)hidePicker:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self.closeDateTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: It works because you set frame sizes, I was trying with auto layout but could not figure out sizing of inputAccessoryView with auto layout ... if I set explicit sizes then it works fine as in your example

Answer (score 0):

self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 43)];

It worked with me when I did the toolbar height less than 44. 43 for an example

when it was 44 it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `UIToolbar` frame you should only set its `autoresizingMask`:

```
self.datePickerToolbar.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

This way you'll have the expected behavior while being device/orientation independent.